# Unity IoC - Deprecated method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Recently I have upgraded IoC assembly of Microsoft.Practices.Unity to version 3.0.1304.1 for .NET target 4.5.  I do not have any compile errors when building my application.  However, I keep seeing a VS code context warning like "**deprecated method Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectedMembers**" when I hover the mouse over "InjectedMembers" in the following code lines:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IRepository>())
                .Configure<InjectedMembers>()
                .ConfigureInjectionFor<Repository>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(DbContext)));
```

So, what is the alternative method and its syntax I should use instead of the "InjectedMembers"?
Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don`t know exactlay what changed between the versions. But this should do the same and solve the problem:

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IRepository> (), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(DbContext)));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your codes are working to me.